# Timestamp out of range for platform on 32bit system

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to run a script I wrote on my Raspberry Pi Zero, but I keep getting the error `OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t`.
I'm relatively certain it's something with the 32-bit ARM architecture of the pi, but I can't seem to figure out a workaround.

Here's the traceback:

```
  File "twitter.py", line 37, in <module>
    t.run.Search(c)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 288, in Search
    run(config, callback)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 209, in run
    get_event_loop().run_until_complete(Twint(config).main(callback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 150, in main
    await task
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 194, in run
    await self.tweets()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 141, in tweets
    await output.Tweets(tweet, self.config, self.conn)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/output.py", line 142, in Tweets
    await checkData(tweets, config, conn)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/output.py", line 116, in checkData
    panda.update(tweet, config)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/storage/panda.py", line 67, in update
    day = weekdays[strftime("%A", localtime(Tweet.datetime))]
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

I've done some searching and found similar(ish) issues, but most of them are with directly converting timestamps, where mine appears to be with setting a time. I've tried rebooting the Pi and immediately running the script to see if the issue is with the Pi being on to long, but that returned the same.

Anyone have any tips?

Thanks, Ben

Comment: Where is your code? What date do you expect `Tweet.datetime` to contain?

Comment: @jordanm pretty sure it's actually a problem with the pi's npt time sync, so I'll be sending this post to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. Thanks for the reply anyways!

Comment: might a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481616/python-overflowerror-creating-date-from-timestamp-in-32bit-system/65494704 which is answered