# Python OverflowError creating date from timestamp in 32bit system

Tags: python, datetime, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I am trying to do a simple conversion of a timestamp to date using python builtin [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module in RaspberryPi4 running Debian Buster.

The conversion works fine in my laptop (64bit Debian) but trows a OverflowError in Debian. The 2 examples follow.

Anyone knows of a simple workaround this issue?
Thank you!

In 64bit Debian system:

```sh
$ python3 -c "from datetime import datetime; d=datetime.fromtimestamp(int("-11486707200")); print(d.year)"
```

```sh
1606
```

In RasbberryPi (32bit) Raspbian system:

```sh
$ python3 -c "from datetime import datetime; d=datetime.fromtimestamp(int("-11486707200")); print(d.year)"
```

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

Comment: The same is can is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868897/timestamp-out-of-range-for-platform-on-32bit-system but no answers given

Comment: In Python's [datetime.fromtimestamp official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) it is mentioned that:


```fromtimestamp() may raise OverflowError, if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C localtime() or gmtime() functions, and OSError on localtime() or gmtime() failure. It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038. ```

Hence the issue seems to ensue from Raspbian's C localtime() or gmtime() functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `-11486707200` is seconds since the epoch (Unix time), you could try to add it as a `timedelta` to the epoch;

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

d = datetime.fromtimestamp(0, tz=timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=-11486707200)
print(d.year)
>>> 1606
```

This works when I test on Python 3.7.9 32 bit. Note that the Raspberry Pi4 CPU has a 64bit architecture, so it's not a "32bit system" in that sense. Not sure if this is an issue of the Pi but I can't test to make sure. So if it persists, maybe ask [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank @MrFuppes. This quite a clean solution. instead of of calculating the `datetime.fromtimestamp` the time delta from the epoch is then added to epoch 0. Which does not produce oveflow error in 32bit system.

Comment: And about the Pi4, although it CPU has a 64bit architecture, the Raspbian ([Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-32-bit)) distro is still using 32bit. However there is a test version running on 64bit https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113047/run-64-bit-raspberry-pi-os-beta-test-version
Also believe that [Debian images for the Raspberry Pi](https://raspi.debian.net/) are making use of 64bit CPU https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi

Comment: @MrCastro: my experience with the Pi is very limited, wasn't aware that the "standard" OS is 32bit debian. So thanks for the info! Glad that the "timedelta-workaround" is working for you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with boto3 on raspberry pi3.

Every time I tried to revalidate a IOT certificate the error occurred:

```
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

I solved it by evaluate the timestamp for anything bigger than 2147480000 (yter 2038) and fixed it to 2147480000 (a convertible timestamp to datetime).

```py
   if value > 2147480000:
       value = 2147480000
```

The traceback:

[image]